# Running cryptsetup commands without sudo permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sudo, disk-encryption, luks

I'm trying to figure out how to run `cryptsetup` commands without the use of `sudo`.

This is so a non-root user could run a script to unlock and mount two `luks`-encrypted drives when they are needed, without requiring `sudo` permissions, as well as running another script to lock and unmount the drives. The drives need to get mounted *only when they are needed*, so I want to do the mounting and decrypting in a script, not on boot with `/etc/fstab` and `/etc/crypttab`. So I need to be able to run the following commands **without sudo**, like this:

`cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/dev1 mapper_name1`

`cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/dev2 mapper_name2`

`cryptsetup luksClose mapper_name1`

`cryptsetup luksClose mapper_name2`

I know that the deal with mounting and granting non-root permissions to the drives involves running `chmod` and `chown` on the mount points and the files within the drive. What I need to know is how to be able to run `cryptsetup` commands without needing `sudo`.

Comment: Would it be an acceptable solution to give a user passwordless `sudo` just for these commands?

Comment: @gronostaj I'm not certain what that entails. I don't want to give non-admin users root access on the system, especially without a password. Unless, is there a way to do this where it only has sudo permissions on certain aspects of the filesystem?

Comment: You can limit `sudo` to specific commands. No password requirement is optional, I just thought it would fit your use case. There's nothing filesystem-specific about `sudo`, it's just launching other commands with elevated privileges, so I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain what's wrong with this question and how it can be improved. Your downvote without any explanation isn't helpful.

Comment: I want to give a non-root user the ability to use cryptsetup commands without giving them permissions to do anything else via sudo

Comment: Are these fixed drives? AFAIK if they are removable, the desktop widget can get them unencrypted/mounted in `/media`.

Comment: @xenoid I don't have a Desktop environment, I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give your users (or groups) limited `sudo` access to just these commands.

Use `visudo` to edit the `sudoers` file (`sudo` configuration). It will open it in default editor and validate it once you're done to prevent breaking `sudo`. Add these at the end:

```
usernameOr%Groupname ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/dev1 mapper_name1
usernameOr%Groupname ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/dev1 mapper_name2
usernameOr%Groupname ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/cryptsetup luksClose mapper_name1
usernameOr%Groupname ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /sbin/cryptsetup luksClose mapper_name2
```

Breakdown of these lines:

- `usernameOr%Groupname` - substitute with username or group name prefixed with `%`
- `ALL` allows all hosts (I don't know how this affects `sudo` in practice, it seems like `ALL` is okay most of the time)
- `(root)` means that they can only impersonate root
- `NOPASSWD:` skips password prompt, remove this part to prompt for password
- `/sbin/cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/dev1 mapper_name1` is obviously your command, with a fully qualified path to the executable

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, rather than just sending me to a link. This is exactly the behavior I was looking for.

Comment: Just a tip: Under Ubuntu 18.04 at least, the command needs to be fully qualified, so instead of `cryptsetup` you need to put `/sbin/cryptsetup` or it will be rejected by visudo.

Comment: @NickGammon Thanks for the correction. It's necessary for all `sudo` versions I think.

Comment: Any time. Your post was otherwise extremely helpful. :)